# Is there a BaaS solution that I can host on my own server?

Tags: javascript, database, nosql, backend, custom-backend

I only recently found out about a bunch of different BaaS offerings like CloudMine, Parse and Apigee and they seem like a great way to put up a quick web app easily without worrying about setting up some php backend or the like.  However, I need this for a project where data availability is key so I MUST have the data available even if I'm offline (application will be hosted locally).  So is there a solution that will give me a really simple JavaScript API to store data easily on a server without rolling my own back end?

Comment: What is your question?  If you're looking for reviews of services, this is not appropriate for StackOverflow.  If you are trying to figure out how to have access to offline data, I suggest throwing an HTML5 tag on your question and removing the parts that are not relevant.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to set up a backend as a turn-key solution.  For instance, if I could host my own version of Parse or something, that would be perfect.  HTML5 does not work cause that limits usage to a single computer / session / browser.  I am writing something that will be used in a small office environment so I want the data hosted on a LAN.

Comment: I understand now... By data available locally, you mean on a server on your network.  I do not know of a product like that, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I mean - there's one product call BaasBox but it's not out yet .. what about some PHP package that obscures the backend logic in some package and just exposes data storage via an ajax interface?

Answer (score 2):

[Deployd](http://www.deployd.com/) might be an option. It's still under 1.0, but it's one you can install at your own server, it's free and open-source.

From their site:

> Deployd is a platform that makes building complex backends simple. 
>   Build APIs for web and mobile apps in minutes instead of days.  Unlike
>   working with a traditional backend, there's no boilerplate, or
>   configuration.  Deployd works right out of the box.  The best part is
>   that **you can run it however and wherever you want** - it's free and open
>   source.